# opengl drawing depth-buffered images

Tags: opengl, depth-buffer, stencil-buffer

when reading on openGL I found something that I could not comprehend. It's regarding this link
[method description](http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter14.html#name18). I have been trying to implement what they are saying but I fail to grasp some elements. Suppose we have 3 images i=0..2  **image**[i][width*height*4] (considering a rgba8 image) and the corresponding depths of each image float **depth**[i][width*height]. How would I go about in implementing the technique described in the link?. I'm also interested if instead of **image** if I have a compressed texture could I still use the technique described there?
  EDIT: I've tried to put the explanation into code but I've only managed to come up with this so far because I could not understand the procedure

```
glDrawPixels(width,height,GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT,GL_FLOAT,depth[0]);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glDepthMask(GL_FALSE);
glEnable(GL_STENCIL_TEST);  
glStencilFunc(GL_EQUAL,0x1,0x1);
glStencilOp(GL_KEEP,GL_KEEP,GL_REPLACE);
glDrawPixels(width,heigh,GL_RGBA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,image[0]);
//don't know what comes next
```

Comment: Even after reading the link, your question is still pretty vague.  Can you give us more detail, and maybe an example of what you've got so far?

Comment: Basically I'm asking how to do depth-sorting using the depth buffer and the stencil buffer if I have the images and the associated depth's stored in memory. After reading that link I thought that it tells you how to do it but I'm unable to completely understand it.